# Sass - Mixin for border

Tags: sass

Is there any mixin for borders where we can define the border direction?

I am using:

```
@mixin border-all($width, $style, $color) {
    border-width: $width;
    border-style: $style;
    border-color: $color;
}
```

It's working but that mixin, as the name says, is for all directions. How can I define the border direction?

I was thinking about something like this: `@mixin border($direction, $width, $style, $color)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I didn't intend to make you so angry. Just delete my question if you are not happy with it.

Comment: @brunodd You cud just use `border-left: 2px solid #000`, you don't need a mixin for this.

Comment: There are complex reasons as to why I am using SASS to do this. I am aware of how to create borders with straight CSS.

Comment: He is asking how it is done, he is not asking if it should be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do that like this:

```
@mixin border($direction, $width, $style, $color) {
  border-#{$direction}: $width $style $color;
}
```

However, I would suggest not using a mixin in this particular case since you're not gaining anything from it over default CSS syntax.

It may be more useful to save your default border styles to variables or mixins for easy reuse.

Examples: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a439bbb5f51125647e21

Comment: Thanks mate! Actually this is what I am doing at the moment.

Comment: A mixin should give you an advantage instead of writing it directly in css.